# Drupal custom page with wildcards in url not working

Tags: 7, views, blocks, path-aliases

I have created a custom page at admin/structure/pages and have set the path to be

```
course-details/%id/%name
```

My intention is that there will be a custom block appearing on this page and the id and the name, in the URI, will pass data to the custom block. I have the block working fine and it is pulling data from a test page URI as expected. I now need to embed this block onto the course-details page, which contains content that must appear for any hit on this page regardless of the id and name.

In the settings => arguments for this page I have set the two arguments to be strings

In settings => access I have set "all criteria must pass"

When I hit the page with no id or name I see the course-details page, at this stage I do not have the custom block enabled, and I am seeing the content that must appear on all course-details pages.

However when I add the id and name, an example is as follows

```
course-details/ACM20110-01V03/certificate-ii-in-animal-studies
```

I am getting a 404 error. It seems the id and name are causing me trouble.

I have spent hours hunting on Google for trying to get my head around why this is not working. I am probably doing something silly.

Could anyone please help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By using the named wildcards %id and %name as wildcards, Drupal will look for functions named id_load() and name_load(). It will pass the values of these wildcards to those functions, and use the return values as the arguments passed to the page callback. If the _load functions are not found, or if a FALSE value is returned, or no value is returned, you will get the error you are seeing.

I'm suspecting you want your path to be:

```
course-details/%/%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an expansion on Jaypans answer and why your item isn't working:

[hook_menu wildcard auto-loader for webform submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224881/hook-menu-wildcard-auto-loader-for-webform-submission/224882#224882)

Each argument in this case will be just `%` - and it will be up to your page callback function to convert those arguments into objects. Though, as strings, that seems a bit tricky and perhaps unreliable but I don't know enough about your application.

I am guessing you are also using something like Page Manager since you did not include a `hook_menu` definition..

Comment: I am using the Drupal admin page manager for this as I wanted to keep it simple